# What is the Java Field Descriptor for Optional<Double>?

Tags: java, types

I know that the Java Field Descriptor for type Double is D, but how would you include the "Optional<>" wrapping the primitive type? Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried to use "Ljava/util/Optional/Double" but it appears that this does not work at all.

Comment: It is `Ljava/util/Optional;`. You missed several things: erasure, primitives vs wrappers...

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I need to include the Optional<Double> and not just all of the Optional<T> types, thanks for the help and it is very helpful!

Comment: There is no specific type descriptor string for `Optional<Double>` ... because *type erasure*.  The erased type's descriptor string is `Ljava/util/Optional;`.  That's it.  Nothing else.

Comment: Then is there a way to differentiate `Option<Double>` and `Option<Integer>`?

Comment: From the field descriptor? No, there is no way to differentiate `Optional<Double>` and `Optional<Integer>`, because erasure.

Comment: Also, you can't use primitive types with generics. `Double` is the wrapper type, and `double` is the primitive type. And the descriptor for `Double` is `Ljava/lang/Double;`, while for `double` it is `D`. (You mix that up in your question.)

Comment: Finally, I hope you are aware of [`java.util.OptionalDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/OptionalDouble.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some of the comments and doing some research. I summarized that there is no way to differentiate between the two because of type erasure